# file pairing procedure in plsql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

So I have a table 'Table1' which has File_Name column, among others. I have to write procedure that checks if every file_name has its pair with the same name. The only difference is in sufix of file_name. Every file_name has .gz sufix and its pair has .fin sufix, and name is the same.

I'm completely new to procedures and plsql in general so I would really appreciate some help. I don't know if I'm on the right track. This is what I have for now, and it has errors of course;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE

PROCEDURE DWHAPND_FILE_PAIRING_CHECK(P_LOAD_TIME     IN DATE,
                                 P_BATCH_NO      IN NUMBER,
                                 P_STATUS       OUT VARCHAR2,
                                 P_MSG          OUT VARCHAR2) IS

CURSOR file_gz IS
SELECT RTRIM(FILE_NAME, '.gz')
FROM TABLE1
WHERE INSTR(FILE_NAME, '.gz', -1, 1)
AND BATCH_NO = P_BATCH_NO
AND LOAD_TIME = P_LOAD_TIME;

L_STATUS   VARCHAR2(10);
L_MSG      VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN

IF(
SELECT RTRIM(FILE_NAME, '.fin') as file_fin
FROM TABLE1
WHERE INSTR(FILE_NAME, '.fin', -1, 1) 
AND BATCH_NO = P_BATCH_NO
AND LOAD_TIME = P_LOAD_TIME) IN file_gz;
THEN L_STATUS := 'OK';
 L_MSG := 'All files are paired';
ELSE L_MSG := 'NOT OK';
 L_MSG := 'Following files are not paired: ' || FILE_NAME IN file_gz;
END IF;
END DWHAPND_FILE_PAIRING_CHECK;
```

Comment: After finding out same filenames, what do you want to do with them?

Comment: Nothing, it's just a check procedure, every file has to have it's pair, otherwise we stop ETL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DWHAPND_FILE_PAIRING_CHECK(P_LOAD_TIME IN DATE,
                                     P_BATCH_NO  IN NUMBER,
                                     P_STATUS    OUT VARCHAR2,
                                     P_MSG       OUT VARCHAR2) IS

  CURSOR file_gz IS
    SELECT RTRIM(FILE_NAME, '.gz') fname
      FROM TABLE1
     WHERE INSTR(FILE_NAME, '.gz', -1, 1)
       AND BATCH_NO = P_BATCH_NO
       AND LOAD_TIME = P_LOAD_TIME
       order by FILE_NAME;

  L_STATUS VARCHAR2(10);
  L_MSG    VARCHAR2(4000);

  type file_fin1 is table of TABLE1.FILE_NAME%type index by pls_integer;

  L_file_fin    file_fin1;

BEGIN

  SELECT RTRIM(FILE_NAME, '.fin') 
        BULK COLLECT INTO L_file_fin
        FROM TABLE1
       WHERE INSTR(FILE_NAME, '.fin', -1, 1)
         AND BATCH_NO = P_BATCH_NO
         AND LOAD_TIME = P_LOAD_TIME
         order by FILE_NAME ;

   For i in 1 .. L_file_fin.count 
    loop      
       for rec in file_gz
       loop
         IF  file_gz(rec).fname = L_file_fin(i)             
          THEN
           L_STATUS := 'OK';
           L_MSG    := 'All files are paired';
         ELSE
            L_MSG := 'NOT OK';
            L_MSG := 'Following files are not paired: ' || FILE_NAME IN file_gz;
         END IF;
         END LOOP;
     END LOOP;

END DWHAPND_FILE_PAIRING_CHECK;
```

Comment: Yeah, makes sense, I figured I'd have to insert loop. I'm just getting 'sql statement ignored' errors on both SELECT blocks, not sure what's the problem, everything looks fine.

Comment: I hope you select will return a single row else there would again be problem. I hope your problm is resolved

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it returns multiple rows.

Comment: No worries, then in that case we need to use 2 loops, In first loop we will take records of 1 table order by name and then compare it with all the table name to see if it exist. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve the problem with just one query

```
with files (file_name) as
(            select 'file1.gz'  from dual
   union all select 'file1.fin' from dual
   union all select 'file2.gz'  from dual
   union all select 'file2.fin' from dual
   union all select 'file3.gz'  from dual
)
select * 
  from ( select file_name, sum(decode(ext,'.gz',1,0)) cnt_gz, sum(decode(ext,'.fin',1,0)) cnt_fin
           from (select substr(file_name,1,instr(file_name,'.')-1) file_name, substr(file_name,instr(file_name,'.')) ext 
                   from files -- table1 in your example
                              --where batch_no = p_batch_no
                              -- and load_time = p_load_time
           )
          group by file_name 
  )  
  where cnt_gz >0 and cnt_fin = 0;
```

Comment: That first part with union all, not sure I understand, because I can't know the exact file names and how many files are there.

Comment: the first part is just to make the example work as a standalone SQL. You should replace "from files" with "from table1" and probably do a cursor loop over the statement

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

To find if any of the files not paired.

```
select a.file_name 
from table1 a
where batch_no = p_batch_no
and load_time = p_load_time
and not exists
(select distinct 1 from table1 b where replace(b.file_name,'.gz','') = replace(b.file_name,'.fin','')
and a.p_load_time = b.p_load_time and a.batch_no = b.batch_no);
```

and for files which are paired.

```
select a.file_name 
from table1 a
where batch_no = p_batch_no
and load_time = p_load_time
and exists
(select distinct 1 from table1 b where replace(b.file_name,'.gz','') = replace(b.file_name,'.fin','')
and a.p_load_time = b.p_load_time and a.batch_no = b.batch_no);
```